# Script. How to sort and move catalogs

Tags: bash, scripting

I have some trouble writing a script. I don't know how to sort and move catalogs.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    mkdir "sd/$line"
done < 1a.txt
```

After reading information from `1a.txt` script will make 3 catalogs named by those words which are in `1a.txt`. After they are created i need to move the last two catalogs to other directory. So, i don't know how to write a command to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
       mkdir "sd/$line"
done < 1a.txt

tail -2 1a.txt | while read line 
do
     mv "sd/$line"   new_place

done
```

Comment: File 1a.txt contains information of 3 words. My script will make 3 catalogs named by those 3 words. After they are created i need to move the last two of them to other directory.

Comment: ok I changed the answer